# What's hanging up this use of map.pool in python?

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, pool

I have a command line program I'm running and I pipe in text as arguments:

somecommand.exe < someparameters_tin.txt

It runs for a while (typically a good fraction of an hour to several hours) and then writes results in a number of text files.  I'm trying to write a script to launch several of these simultaneously, using all the cores on a many core machine.  On other OSs I'd fork, but that's not implemented in many scripting languages for Windows.  Python's multiprocessing looks like it might do the trick so I thought I'd give it a try, although I don't know python at all.  I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

I wrote a script (below) which I point to a directory, if finds the executable and input files, and launches them using pool.map and a pool of n, and a function using call.  What I see is that initially (with the first set of n processes launched) it seems fine, using n cores 100%.  But then I see the processes go idle, using no or only a few percent of their CPUs.  There are always n processes there, but they aren't doing much.  It appears to happen when they go to write the output data files, and once it starts everything bogs down, and overall core utilization ranges from a few percent to occasional peaks of 50-60%, but never gets near 100%.

If I can attach it (edit: I can't, at least for now) here's a plot of run times for the processes.  The lower curve was when I opened n command prompts and manually kept n processes going at a time, easily keeping the computer near 100%.  (The line is regular, slowly increasing from near 0 to 0.7 hours across 32 different processes varying a parameter.)  The upper line is the result of some version of this script -- the runs times are inflated by about 0.2 hours on average and are much less predictable, like I'd taken the bottom line and added 0.2 + a random number.

Here's a link to the plot:
[Run time plot](http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6007/5978537383_4c34b9843b_o.png)

Edit: and now I think I can add the plot.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count, Lock
from subprocess import call
import glob, time, os, shlex, sys
import random

def launchCmd(s):
    mypid = os.getpid()
    try:
        retcode = call(s, shell=True)
        if retcode < 0:
            print >>sys.stderr, "Child was terminated by signal", -retcode
        else:
            print >>sys.stderr, "Child returned", retcode
    except OSError, e:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # ******************************************************************
    # change this to the path you have the executable and input files in
    mypath = 'E:\\foo\\test\\'
    # ******************************************************************

    startpath = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(mypath)
    # find list of input files
    flist = glob.glob('*_tin.txt')
    elist = glob.glob('*.exe')
    # this will not act as expected if there's more than one .exe file in that directory!
    ex = elist[0] + ' < '

    print
    print 'START'
    print 'Path: ', mypath
    print 'Using the executable: ', ex
    nin = len(flist)
    print 'Found ',nin,' input files.'
    print '-----'
    clist = [ex + s for s in flist]
    cores = cpu_count()
    print 'CPU count ', cores
    print '-----'

    # ******************************************************
    # change this to the number of processes you want to run
    nproc = cores -1
    # ******************************************************

    pool = Pool(processes=nproc, maxtasksperchild=1)    # start nproc worker processes
    # mychunk = int(nin/nproc)      # this didn't help
    # list.reverse(clist)           # neither did this, or randomizing the list
    pool.map(launchCmd, clist)      # launch processes
    os.chdir(startpath)             # return to original working directory
    print 'Done'
```

Comment: You look like you really know what you are doing; this looks like good Python for a self-proclaimed total newbie.  One question: when the CPU is idle, is the hard disk super busy?  Theoretically if your processes produced huge amounts of output, the processes might be mostly idle while waiting for the disk to write everything.  This would be especially true if caching wasn't working for some reason.

Comment: It does appear that (as reported by resource monitor) the disk activity spikes when the cpu usage drops (which happens as the first processes start to write their output), and then stays near 100% until well after all the processes are done.  The disk queue also goes to 50.  I'm curious why this would be the case here but not when I manually execute the same commands from multiple command lines -- it does seem like something is being shared (badly).

Comment: I should add: I don't care what order these processes complete in.  In the example I'm trying now the shortest ones run first.  Randomizing or reversing the order might help a little but does not make a large difference.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance that the processes are trying to write to a common file?  Under Linux it would probably just work, clobbering data but not slowing down; but under Windows one process might get the file and all the other processes might hang waiting for the file to become available.

If you replace your actual task list with some silly tasks that use CPU but don't write to disk, does the problem reproduce?  For example, you could have tasks that compute the md5sum of some large file; once the file was cached the other tasks would be pure CPU and then a single line output to stdout.  Or compute some expensive function or something.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* I know this. When you call `map`, it breaks the list of tasks into 'chunks' for each process. By default, it uses chunks large enough that it can send one to each process. This works on the assumption that all the tasks take about the same length of time to complete.

In your situation, presumably the tasks can take very different amounts of time to complete. So some workers finish before others, and those CPUs sit idle. If that's the case, then this should work as expected:

```
pool.map(launchCmd, clist, chunksize=1)
```

Less efficient, but it should mean that each worker gets more tasks as it finishes until they're all complete.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to make a difference.